# Rundeck - Failed to read SSH Private Key stored at path - Path does not exist

Tags: continuous-deployment, rundeck

I am running the Rundeck `war` file directly

`java -jar rundeck-3.0.17-20190311.war`

I get this error message when I trigger a build.

```
Failed to read SSH Private key stored at path: 
keys/rundeck.pem: org.rundeck.storage.api.StorageException: 
Path does not exist: keys/rundeck.pem

Failed: ConfigurationFailure: Failed to read SSH 
Private key stored at path: keys/rundeck.pem
```

It makes sense that the reference in the Default Node Executor is invalid and that Rundeck cannot find the .pem file.

I've tried

- referencing the full working directory (/home/user/rundeck/keys/rundeck.pem) It wants the location to start with `keys/`.
- referencing it to its relative path (`keys/rundeck.pem`)
- copied the `keys` directory to `/home/user/`

In desperation, I ran `chmod 700` on the pem file.

Most of the questions and examples I found were on older versions of Rundeck.

I'd like to know where the .pem file must be configured and how it should be referenced. Any other information that could help me configure the SSH keys will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the key using the GUI and use the path that you are defined in your resources.xml.

For add your key, you can follow this. Although the video is based on Rundeck 2.x it is valid for Rundeck 3.x:

Check that https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOA-kWse22g

And for generate your resources.xml file select your new project and go to Project Settings > Edit Nodes > Click on "Configure Nodes" button (up to right) > Click on "Add Sources +" Button > Select "+ File" option > in "Format" field select "resourcexml" and fill the path in "File Path" field (put the file name at the end, usually "resources.xml"), then  select "Generate", "Include Server Node" and "Writeable" checkboxes and click on "Save" button.